# How to log into syslog if a service is stopped with systemd

Tags: centos, systemd, services

I use Centos7, and I created a service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Audit Daemon
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/opt/MyAuditDaemon
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx256m -jar MyAuditDaemon.jar
TimeoutSec=30
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to log if this service stops.

I placed a ShutdownHook in the java program, so when I stop it with systemctl stop myauditdaemon.service , it writes into the syslog. This also works when I terminate it with SIGTERM.

But when I use the shutdown, or reboot command, there is no message in the syslog.

I also tried the ExecStop parameter in the service file:

```
ExecStop=/usr/bin/logger -p local5.info -n localhost My Audit Service stopped.
```

This works only too when I stop the service with systemctl, or SIGTERM.

How should I log the shutdown of this daemon?

Comment: Did you `enable` the service so it starts automatically at boot, and so stops  automatically at shutdown?

Comment: yeah. i did. it starts automatically at every boot, and i can see the log about the start in the syslog too. if i stop it with systemctl stop, it works too. The log also appears correctly in syslog. But if i reboot/shutdown the server, i cant see anything in the log about it, only the start record after the next boot.

Comment: You might try adding `rsyslog.service` as a dependency in the `After=` line.

Comment: you were right, that was the problem.